# How to make the hover attributes stays when it is clicked/active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the hover attributes stay when it is clicked/active?

Add-on:
   Close the submenu when other submenu open.
   I want to close the submenu when I want to open other submenu. How to do that?

[Click Me](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb4yf4gh/)

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Walk-In<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Members<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </li>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Sales<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Inventory<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Suppliers<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="show-sub"><a href="#">Reports<span class="sub-arrow"></span></a>    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.show-sub').click(function(e){
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });

    $(".show-sub ul").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300italic,300);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
}

.user {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 15px;  
}

.logo a {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #070807;
}

.logo a span {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1AC93A;
}

nav {
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: :auto;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    padding: 15px
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav li a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

/*nav li a:focus {
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
}*/

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

/*nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}*/

/*nav ul li.tap > ul {
    display: block;
}*/

nav .sub-arrow:after {
    content: '\203A';
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

nav .sub-arrow:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: along the :hover also use :focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class when you click the element and change your css to use both the hover and class:

```
nav li a:hover, .active {
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.show-sub').click(function(e){
    // This closes all active menus before opening the clicked menu
    $('.active').removeClass('active').children('ul').slideUp();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

*edited to close all other menus first

Comment: the other submenu didn't close when I open other submenu. It should close when I clicked other menu to open submenu. How to do that?

Comment: one last thing is, I want to close the submenu whenever I clicked to other menus

Comment: I've added slideUp to the JS above, should work for you.

Comment: WOW! NICE! IT WORKS! HAHAHA THANKS! :)